# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' (only as root)

Tags: python

So I'm having this weird issue.

I just installed server 18.04.1 LTS. The purpose of this server is to run scheduled Python scripts.

I can run my script just fine when authenticated with the user-account created during installation. But it won't run when scheduled with CRON (sudo crontab -e).

So... I set root password, authenticate and try running script and receive error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'". So... I install pandas (sudo apt-get install python-pandas) and re-run. Same error

Comment: Please add output of `pip freeze | grep pandas`, `su -c "pip freeze | grep pandas"` and `apt-cache policy python-pandas` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your purpose, tt's probably a safer choice to not use root to run any scripts on your server.

*(I don't actually know if running cron scripts with root can create a vulnerability or not, but better safe than sorry i guess)*.

With that in mind, I think you could solve this by either

1) setting the permission for your user (the one that runs the script successfully) in the cron.allow file:

> usually in the path `/usr/lib/cron/cron.allow`, simply adding the username in a separate line.

or

2) setting a custom env for the script:

```
HOME=user-home-directory
LOGNAME=user-login-id
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:.
SHELL=/usr/bin/sh
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/pythonX.X
```

For more detailed information check this [crontrab reference](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Hope that helps.